# Gitignore: Wildcard suffix only in top directory

Tags: git, gitignore

Say my file structure is

```
 main
 main/.gitignore
 main/asd.bar
 main/asd2.bar
 main/subdir/foo.bar
 main/subdir2/asdasd.bar
```

where `main` is the top directory.

I want to ignore all files with `.bar` suffix, but only in the top directory.
My approaches simply ignore them for all subdirs... how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
/main/*.bar
```

That will anchor the rule to the `/main` top folder.
This assume the git repo folder is in the parent folder of `main/`.
If it actually is in `main/` (meaning there is a `main/.git` folder), then the rule is:

```
/*.bar
```

Again, only the top folder `*.bar` files would be ignored because of the anchor "`/`".

At any point, you can check which rule is still ignoring your file with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file
```

Comment: Upvoted for the useful check-ignore command. Unfortunately, it revealed that the first suggestion did not work, it's not ignoring anything.

Comment: @FooBar Is your Git repo in the parent folder of main? Or is it in main (do you see a main/.git folder)?

Comment: @FooBar If it is in main/, then the rule would be `/*.bar`: I have edited my answer accordingly.